# Connect to Sony Camera using external wifi but connect to internet using internal wifi. (2 connections) on Mac

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, wifi-configuration, camera

Hello I am running a sophisticated product photography setup using Mac, Shutterstream, and a Sony a5100 Camera.

I use shutterstream to connect to the camera wirelessly which allows me to take photos from my computer and control the camera settings from my computer.

However this leaves my wireless on my macbook "tied up" and I am unable to be connected to the internet while I am using it to take photos.

I have a Netis Wireless Duel Band USB Adapter that is compatible with my mac (although im having trouble getting it to work haha)

That being said.. Is it possible to use this Netis USB Wireless Adapter to connect to the camera and use my internal wifi to remain connected to the internet? IS THERE an app for that?

Thanks :)

Comment: The reason why it's "tied up" is because it works on an ah-hoc connection. Yes, it should be possible to do what you want but it's all about settings, not apps. Of course, all the hardware must be correctly installed (using proprietary drivers if it must be). If you can't use the other WiFi device "normally" (as in infrastructure, connected to an access point), you won't be able to use it ad-hoc.

Comment: So no one has done this before and the steps arent laid out anywhere that you know of?

I installed the driver for the netis wifi connector.. But that didnt create 2 areas to connect.

Comment: I know almost nothing about Macs. I use Ubuntu (99,9%) and Windows (0.1%). Both can do it so yours must be able as well.

Comment: Ok thats good to know. Thanks! Its for a setup at work which i have limited time during the day to setup. If anyone comes across this and knows of a tutorial or from personal experience then it would be mucho appreciated!